# Parse abstraction layer using Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

So I am fairly new to Swift and am not quite clear on best practices with Protocol Oriented Programming yet and could use some advice. What I am trying to do is to create an an abstraction layer on top of Parse that lets me load objects from Parse and transform them into structs/classes that implement the "BackendLoading" protocol. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

protocol BackendLoading {
    typealias AbstractType
    static var backendDBKey: String { get }
    static var propertyKeyNames: [String] { get }
    init()
    init(parameterDictionary: [String: AnyObject])
}

protocol BackendLoader {
    func loadAllObjectsFromBackend<T where T: BackendLoading>(classType: T.Type) -> [T];
}

extension BackendLoader {
    func getPropertyDictionaryFromType<T where T: BackendLoading>(classType: T.Type) -> [String: String] {
        var returnDictionary = [String: String]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: T())
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let label = child.label {
                returnDictionary[label] = label
            }
        }
        return returnDictionary
    }
}

struct ParseBackendLoader: BackendLoader {

    func loadAllObjectsFromBackend<T where T: BackendLoading>(classType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var returnArray = [T]()
        let parseObjectArray = loadAllParseObjectsFromBackend(classType)
        let propertyDictionary = getPropertyDictionaryFromType(T)
        for parseObject in parseObjectArray {
            let extractedDictionary = extractPropertiesFromParseObject(parseObject, propertyDictionary: propertyDictionary)
            let object = T(parameterDictionary: extractedDictionary)
            returnArray.append(object)
        }
        return returnArray
    }

    func extractPropertiesFromParseObject(parseObject: PFObject, propertyDictionary: [String: String]) -> [String: AnyObject] {
        var returnDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        for (key, _) in propertyDictionary {
            if let parseValue = parseObject[key] {
                returnDictionary[key] = parseValue
            }
        }
        return returnDictionary;
    }

    func loadAllParseObjectsFromBackend<T where T: BackendLoading>(classType: T.Type) -> [PFObject] {
        do {
            let query = PFQuery(className: T.backendDBKey)
            return try query.findObjects()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return [PFObject]()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the object that I am using from my unit tests that is hooked up to a backend equivalent in Parse:

```
class TestLoading: BackendLoading {
    typealias AbstractType = TestLoading
    static var backendDBKey = "TestObject"
    static var propertyKeyNames = ["testObjectString"]
    var testObjectString: String?
    required init() {}

    required init(parameterDictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if let testObjectStringFromDict = parameterDictionary["testObjectString"] as? String {
            testObjectString = testObjectStringFromDict
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working...just wondering if I am going about this the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One remark apart from the protocoll design: depending on the error thrown by findObjects() a specific error handling is necessary. I would not generally catch the error and log it but pass it to the caller. Some errors are automatically recoverable, some need user interaction, some can or must be ignored. E.g. a turned on Flight-Mode should be reported to the user. Think on error handling early in the API design - eventually you can not ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...this is far from a finished product...just kind of wondering if I am going down the right path.

Comment: Is the ParseBackendLoader really stateless (no stored properties)? Currently there is no need for a class type.

Comment: It's stateless as of yet. I will probably convert it to a struct if it stays that way.

Comment: getPropertyDictionaryFromType could be moved to BackendLoading as a protocol default implementation. (or default implementation of a protocol extension) Basically a "type" describing itself. Unfortunately it's christmas and I have no compiler at hand to test this... It just seems strange to pass a T.Type to a func which then returns a description of the very type. It's feels more natural if a type is describing itself.

Comment: But eventually I do not understand the advantage. I have written my own Swift framework for a REST API and also was not able to make it more convenient by using Mirror. At the end, in the initializer of TestObject you still have to write manually testObjectString = valueFromDict. You could also directly pass the ParseObject in to it. Or do I miss something... ?

Comment: I don't want to tightly bind Parse objects to my data model which is what would happen if I passed the Parse object directly to my test class. That way, if I want to replace Parse, all I have to do is swap out the BackEndLoader.

Comment: I see. Well, then it makes sense. Looks quite ok. I have bound my data model to the JSON type and do not expect this to be a problem in the future. But moving from Parse to a "full blown" backend is quite likely, yes. Good luck.